# why I can't use code files from app_code in my code asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, app-code

I am working on an asp.net web app, and I have few classes in my app_code, but for some reason I can't use any of them in my code. I tried using the same namespace, I tried without any namespace in both files, but nothing helps.

This is my page code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using LinkedIn;
using LinkedIn.ServiceEntities;


namespace Authentication
{
    public partial class LinkedinMoreInfo : LinkedinBasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And my code in the class:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;

using LinkedIn;

namespace Authorisation
{
    public class LinkedInBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string AccessToken
        {
            get { return (string)Session["AccessToken"]; }
            set { Session["AccessToken"] = value; }
        }

        private InMemoryTokenManager TokenManager
        {
            get
            {
                var tokenManager = (InMemoryTokenManager)Application["TokenManager"];
                if (tokenManager == null)
                {
                    string consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkedInConsumerKey"];
                    string consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkedInConsumerSecret"];
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey) == false)
                    {
                        tokenManager = new InMemoryTokenManager(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
                        Application["TokenManager"] = tokenManager;
                    }
                }

                return tokenManager;
            }
        }

        protected WebOAuthAuthorization Authorization
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Authorization = new WebOAuthAuthorization(this.TokenManager, this.AccessToken);

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string accessToken = this.Authorization.CompleteAuthorize();
                if (accessToken != null)
                {
                    this.AccessToken = accessToken;

                    Response.Redirect(Request.Path);
                }

                if (AccessToken == null)
                {
                    this.Authorization.BeginAuthorize();
                }
            }

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what can be the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are `Authentication` and `Authorisation` your "same namespace"?

Comment: Have you made sure App_Code is included in the project? And does it work if you move the classes from App_Code to your project's root directory?

Comment: @James I tried that too, it didn't work, same mistake, and yes it's included in the project. mellamokb, I did a typo with the 'Authorisation', but I tried with 'Authentication' too, I am getting the same error. ChrisF 'the type or namespace name could not be found...'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go into the properties of the files, and change the `Build Action` to `Compile`

Comment: Thanks James, you are the man. If you have some time, can you explain how that change fixed my problem? Thanks a lot and have a good day.

Comment: You're very welcome. Setting the build action to `Compile` ensures that the code file is compiled into the build output.

Comment: I've reached my vote limit but good thinking, I wouldn't have thought of this! What are the purposes of the other Build Actions?

Comment: The build actions tell Visual Studio what to do with a file when a build is executed. This article explains the different build actions in detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your base page is name `LinkedInBasePage`, then you need to inherit from `LinkedInBasePage` instead of `LinkedinBasePage`

`public partial class LinkedinMoreInfo : Authorisation.LinkedInBasePage {`

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the issue of accessing files in the `App_Code` directory.